# how to create textviews and image horizontally in android programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I need to place this three text and an image horizontally one after another. How to proceed?

My code is as follows:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_placeorder,
            container, false);
    ScrollView scrl=new ScrollView(getActivity());
     final LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(getActivity());
     ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
     scrl.addView(ll);
     for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     TextView time=new TextView(getActivity());
     time.setText("07.23"+i);
     ll.addView(time);
    TextView orderId=new TextView(getActivity());
     orderId.setText("ORDER:03987"+i);
     ll.addView(orderId); 
     TextView dollarPrice = new TextView(getActivity());
     dollarPrice.setText("$39.55"+i);
     ll.addView(dollarPrice); 
     ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());
     image.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_right); 
     ll.addView(image);
     }
```

Screenshot is as follows:

[image]

Comment: change  ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); to ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

Comment: no this makes to scroll horizontally @NarendraPal

Comment: You need ScrollView & inside it take linearlayout. Then in that you can add components you want. It means your parent view will be scrollview not linear/relative layout.

Comment: See concept of horizontal listview. So you will get clear idea of that.

Comment: you can set image of arrow to second textview i mean you can set it drawableRight to 2nd textview it will be easy to your requirment

Comment: i don't want to use listview @RIT

Comment: Yes i know. Its for your reference that how to design xml for adding items horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to create all the views dynamically. Just create xml for items and inflate it inside loop. Like..

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout layoutmain;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        layoutmain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutmain);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(
                    R.layout.row, null);
            ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutmain)).addView(viewToLoad);
        }

TextView txt = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    txt.setText("Ship");
    ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutmain)).addView(txt);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

        View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(
                R.layout.row, null);
        ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutmain)).addView(viewToLoad);
    }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PROCESSED" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutmain"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtfirst"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="07.23" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtsecond"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ORDER:0378945" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtthird" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="$36.55" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use another LinearLayout with orientation Horizontal, and set that to the vertical LinearLayout. So that your scroll won't be affected.

Something like this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_placeorder,
            container, false);
ScrollView scrl=new ScrollView(getActivity());
LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(getActivity());
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LinearLayout l2=new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    l2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    TextView time=new TextView(getActivity());
    time.setText("07.23"+i);
    l2.addView(time);
    TextView orderId=new TextView(getActivity());
    orderId.setText("ORDER:03987"+i);
    l2.addView(orderId);
    TextView dollarPrice = new TextView(getActivity());
    dollarPrice.setText("$39.55"+i);
    l2.addView(dollarPrice);
    ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_right);
    l2.addView(image);
    l1.addView(l2);
}
scrl.addView(ll);
```

This will add a new linear layout with 3 textview and imageview in a single line in main outer layout which will be vertical, and scrollable.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in your xml layout add horizontal LinearLayout and put your object on that like this :

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"/>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and in your class set this layout horizontal or vertical like that :

```
LinearLayout m =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
m.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```